# How to properly set the parameters of LIBSVM.scale() with the Android Java wrapper of LIBSVM

Tags: java, android, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to use [yctung's LIBSVM-wrapper for Android](https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSVM) to classifiy 262-dimensional datapoints on Android. I managed to train a classifier on a training-dataset with ~240 datapoints and successfully tested it on a 15-datapoints test-dataset. Both of the datasets were scaled just by calling svm.scale as yctung suggests it:

```
    svm.scale(appFolderPath + "trainingdata", appFolderPath + "trainingdata_scaled");
    svm.train("-t 0 "/* svm kernel */ + appFolderPath + "trainingdata_scaled " + appFolderPath + "model");
    svm.scale(appFolderPath + "testdata", appFolderPath + "testdata_scaled");
    svm.predict(appFolderPath + "testdata_scaled " + appFolderPath + "model " + appFolderPath + "result");
```

I got pretty good results with that, so i went on to try the model on a single datapoint generated at runtime. Of course i had to scale the data befor i could classify it (so "predict" is a file containing only one datapoint with 262 attributes):

```
        svm.scale(appFolderPath + "predict", appFolderPath + "predict_scaled");
        svm.predict(appFolderPath + "predict_scaled " + appFolderPath + "model " + appFolderPath + "predicted");
```

But instead of a scaled datapoint, svm.scale returns just a "1" and nothing else. 
I think this might be, because .scale tries to compare and scale the corresponding attributes in a dataset relativly to each other, so it gets an error if there is only one datapoint in a set. 
Is this correct?
And if so, what could i do to scale the newly generated datapoint relativly to the trainingdata set and not just to itself? Is it possible to set the scaling parameters manualy, which would allow me to scale every datapoint with the same "reference" or settings? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess the best way to do this is by writing my own scale-funktion. Shouldnt be to hard.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is stuck at the same question:
My solution was to append every new datapoint at the end of a copy of my training dataset, scale the copy with AndroidLibSvm.scale() and retrieve the now properly scaled datapoint from the output-file. Works fine and is much better than any hardcoded solution.